# using backbone/ember makes django being a simple REST API?

Tags: django, backbone.js, ember.js

I have read a couple of articles about using new JS frameworks like Backbone.js or Ember.js

I have come up to this statement:
If I use a JS framework like Backbone.js/Ember.js, I then move the logic from the back-end (Django) to the front-end.

Therefore, will Django actually be used only for its Models?
Does that mean that Django Views and Django Template are not needed anymore and the Django back-end is kinda turn into a "basic" REST API that will be consumed by the front end.

Do you agree? Is it then the purpose of Django in this case?

Is turning the django backend into a REST API one of the most suitable use case when using a framework like Backbone.js/Ember.js for the front-end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django is perfectly fine to be used this way, you still get the admin, the models, the orm and all the third-party plugins. However, it isn't blazingly fast, so if you're doing simple document level, non-relational REST mapping, you might wan't to look into node.js and mongoDB for instance.

If you're sticking with django (like we are, we like the structure it gives us), you can use one of the REST plugins:

- [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) A perfect match since DRF 2.0, under very active development!
- [Django Tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) (checkout [backbone-tastypie.js](https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie) for integration)
- [Django Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/7c90898072ce/piston) (might be a bit stale or has development picked up lately?)

If you only want to work with frontend development, checkout the Backend-as-a-Service places like [cloudmine.me](http://cloudmine.me) or [firebase.com](http://firebase.com) that handle all backend stuff for you, for a price of course.

Comment: Ok i have tried the first two. However the integration with backbone does not look straightforward. It sounds like i have to override some things on backbone... Is there some handy ways to make one or the other work right away with backbone in a simple way with a minimum of configuration? Thanks.

Comment: We have a pretty heavily customized DRF and Backbone setup with overridden sync and more. We use DRF not because of out-of-the-box compatibility, but more because the ease of customization. I'll update my answer with some more info

Comment: Ok si i guess i'll have to go through the customization of Backbone sync etc anyway.

Comment: Check the backbone-tastypie.js (link in my answer), it might help you!

Comment: and with DRF, do I have to override Backbone as well?

Comment: I don't think so, just adding the id and removing the url attributes from the resource in DRF (DRF defaults to using the URL as canonical id for an object, while that works and is very RESTy, numerical ids are easier to work with in backbone)

Answer (score 1):

Django may seem unnecessary once you start thinking about single page solutions and Javascript applications, but if you want your site to be 'fail proof' it wouldn't be impossible to develop both a client side Javascript version of the site as well as a backend django side incase the user, or your site's javascript, fails at some level. Of course this requires creating your site twice, and probably isn't needed in the age of modern browsers, but such would be one of the few instances where you would mix the two for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's about it. You can use it to manage authentication to resources and such and maybe use a main view for your application but you won't need to use the server side templating since these frameworks are made to work with json/xml response.

That's why a lot of people are moving to lighter backend/backbone or ember combo instead of a complete solution like django. You can also use your django for caching json response which makes your application appears faster.

Comment: Do you have any example of lighter backend that can replace Django in this case?

Answer (score 0):

We are doing that and use django-piston to make it easier on you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you make your entire website under Django and only one page will be a "single app page" using backbone.js, usually that page is a very interactive page, with lots of small updates that occur frequently and need to be shown very fast to the user. This page, because of the large number of changes and user interactions is constructed on the client-side so that you are using his PC resources and not the server's, the rest of the pages can use django because it offers you a very stable and secure framework for the server-side